# Text editing in visual basic

Tags: regex, vb.net

At the push of a button, I need a way to remove everything but numbers from a textbox and group numbers 6 in a row with a comma `,` to separate them.

**Example:**

Text in textbox:

```
416782  167490ai|189037jkn
```

expected result:

```
416782,167490,189037
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

I've got as far as this, and it gives me the right output and removes everything but numbers. I just need to add a comma every 6 characters.

```vb
    Private Sub copypdmbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _ 
        Handles copypdmbutton.Click

        Dim input As String = textbox.Text
        Dim output As String = textbox2.Text

        output = (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "[^\d]", "")) 
        'removes everything except numbers
    
        textbox2.Text = output

    End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Ive gotten as far as this:

    Private Sub copypdmbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles copypdmbutton.Click

        Dim newString As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()


    End Sub

But I am not quite sure as to how to edit the string to get the results I need

Comment: Don't try to go from an idea to code. Think about how you would do it if it was a manual process. Write down the steps you would perform. Break the steps up into the smallest units you can and formalise them into an algorithm. That takes no programming experience at all, so a beginner will have no issues as long as they are prepared to think through the problem. Once you have an algorithm, THEN you can write to implement those steps specifically. If you get stuck, you can tell us EXACTLY what step it is that you're stuck on.

Comment: You can use Regex.Matches with patter `\d+` + `String.Join(","c, [Enumerable Of Matches])`

Comment: Are the digits already in batches of 6 and you only need to replace the intervening characters with a comma? If so, `output = Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9]+", ",").Trim(",".ToCharArray())`.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately for us, a `String` is a sequential collection of `Char`. We can use this fact by looping through each `Char` in the `String` from the text box. We only add the numbers (digits) to the new string.

I then build the result string using `Substring(start Index, length)` followed by a comma.

This code only works if the length of `numberString` is evenly divisible by 6. The `Mod` operator tells us this. I will leave it to you to decide how to handle the edge case. Hint: The last `sb.Append` can use `Substring(start Index)` The missing second parameters means that the substring will continue to the end of the original string.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = "416782 167490ai|189037jkn"
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim s = TextBox1.Text
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For Each c As Char In s
        If Char.IsDigit(c) Then
            sb.Append(c)
        End If
    Next
    Dim numberString = sb.ToString
    sb.Clear()
    If numberString.Length Mod 6 = 0 Then
        For i = 0 To numberString.Length - 6 Step 6
            sb.Append(numberString.Substring(i, 6) & ",")
        Next
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString.Trim(","c)
End Sub
```

Comment: @AndrewMorton I edited the definition of String. I am not sure how a sequential collection is defined in reference to the .net framework but is behaves like an array or `List( Of Char)` in my For loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you NuGet "System.Interactive" to get the `Buffer` operator, then this code does the job:

```
Dim input As String = "3434jh34kjh3b4k34m34kj43434"

Dim output As String =
        String.Join(
            ",", _
            input _
                .Where(Function (x) Char.IsDigit(x)) _
                .Buffer(6) _
                .Select(Function (xs) String.Concat(xs)))
                
Console.WriteLine(output)
```

For my sample input I get this out:

```
343434,343434,43434
```